# Empty home folder

Tags: system-installation

I recently installed Ubuntu on my computer. I have 2 hard drives: 500 GB and a 2 TB. Thinking I would have plenty of room for my videos and images I set the large drive to be /home

I log into the freshly installed OS. I set a few basic settings such as mirroring my 2 monitors. My settings don't save.

Next I realize my applications don't run. For example I try to run the Firefox web browser it acts like it will run with the spinning cursor image. But it doesn't open up, no error message.

I open file explorer and see my /home folder is empty. I expect to see /home/Dave I think this is my problem. My home folder is where my settings should be saved.

What do I do? Can I fix this install? Should I try to reinstall Ubuntu making sure the settings for the home folder are correct? I don't even know what I did wrong during the install.

```
----------------------------------------------------------
MORE INFO:
23.04 Desktop

dave@ubuntu2023:~$ cat /etc/fstab
 /etc/fstab: static file system information.
 Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
 device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
 that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
 <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
 / was on /dev/sda3 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/4feb52ca-71b4-4463-b2cf-f7aece53b290 / ext4 defaults 0 1
 /boot was on /dev/sda2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/c0b95236-d0e5-423d-b1e9-80c511ed5a87 /boot ext4 defaults 0 1
 /home was on /dev/sdb1 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/ffdfa468-05e1-45d5-83d3-9518bddbc3c5 /home ext4 defaults 0 1

/swap.img   none    swap    sw  0   0

dave@ubuntu2023:~$ lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,parttype
NAME FSTYPE   SIZE FSUSED LABEL PARTLABEL MOUNTPOINT PARTTYPE
sda         465.8G                                   
├─sda1
│               1M                                   21686148-6449-6e6f-744e-656564454649
├─sda2
│    ext4     512M 180.8M                 /boot      0fc63daf-8483-4772-8e79-3d69d8477de4
└─sda3
     ext4   465.3G    13G                 /          0fc63daf-8483-4772-8e79-3d69d8477de4
sdb           1.8T                                   
└─sdb1
     ext4     1.8T     2M                 /home      0fc63daf-8483-4772-8e79-3d69d8477de4
sdc             0B                                   
sdd             0B                                   
sde             0B                                   
sdf             0B                                   
sdg             0B                                   
sdh          28.8G                                   
└─sdh1
     vfat    28.8G   160K KINGSTON
                                          /media/dav 0xc

dave@ubuntu2023:~$ getent passwd dave
dave:x:1000:1000:David Norman:/home/dave:/bin/bash
dave@ubuntu2023:~$ 
/dev/disk/by-uuid/c0b95236-d0e5-423d-b1e9-80c511ed5a87 /boot ext4 defaults 0 1
 /home was on /dev/sdb1 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/ffdfa468-05e1-45d5-83d3-9518bddbc3c5 /home ext4 defaults 0 1
/swap.img   none    swap    sw  0   0

dave@ubuntu2023:~$ pwd
/home/dave
```

So it looks like I do have a home drive /home/dave
My 2 TB drive has a "home" folder but it's not the folder with my home folder in it.
It looks like maybe I need to reinstall. I can't remember the exact options but I did the partitioning during the OS install.
Here's how I set the partitions:
1 MB BIOS Boot Partition
512MB Boot
rest of the drive is root /
large (2TB) separate drive is /home

When I set the 2TB drive I was asked for the mountpoint. I think I set it to /home

Comment: Did you use Something Else and choose your /home partition as /home during install? Post these: `cat /etc/fstab` & `lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,parttype`

Comment: Please [edit] your Question and show us the command and redult of `getent passwd Dave;getent passwd dave`. Do not reply via Add Comment.

Comment: Please format copy-pasted output as `code` using the {_} icon above the edit question window.

Comment: Anyone have any idea how to fix this?